# on second click remove text from button click

Tags: javascript, html, text, input, onclick

How can I remove the text "Input this text in textarea on click" when I click the "Input text button" for the second time? Is it possible without javascript?

```
<textarea name=\"text\" rows=\"10\" cols=\"50\">" . htmlspecialchars($arr["text"]) . "</textarea>



<INPUT TYPE="button" NAME="insert" VALUE="Input text button" onClick="this.form.text.value=this.form.text.value.concat('Input this text in textarea on click');">
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<form>
    <textarea name="text" id="text" rows="10" cols="50"></textarea>
    <input type="button" name="insert" id="insert" value="Input text button"  />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('insert').onclick = function() {
        var txt  = 'Input this text in textarea on click',
            area = document.getElementById('text');

        area.value = area.value.indexOf(txt) != -1 ? area.value.replace(txt, '') : area.value + txt;
    }
</script>
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/atRXz/)